# Magento test automation framework testcase creation

Tags: magento

I'm using this is my custom testcase in magento test automation framework.

public function test_WithInvalidPassword($wrongPasswords, $errorMessage)
    {

```
    //Data
    $userData = $this->loadData('generic_admin_user', $wrongPasswords, array('email', 'user_name'));
    //Steps
    $this->adminUserHelper()->createAdminUser($userData);
    //Verifying
    $this->assertTrue($this->errorMessage($errorMessage), $this->messages);
    $this->assertTrue($this->verifyMessagesCount(), $this->messages);
}


public function data_invalidPassword()
{
    return array(
        array(array(
                'password' => '1234567890',
                'password_confirmation' => '1234567890',
            ), 'invalid_password')
    );
}
```

Here, it showing me the error like "SystemStores_CreateTest::test_WithInvalidPassword()
Missing argument 1 for SystemStores_CreateTest::test_WithInvalidPassword()" and the same functionality is working in the default mtaf-testcases.

can any one suggest for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a data provider to supply the values for the arguments.

You would need to add the `@dataProvider` annotation to the docblock comment for the test function.

**You can find more information on this page:** ecomdev.org/2011/02/01/phpunit-and-magento-yes-you-can.html under the heading 'Data Providers'.

**There's also some information in the PHPUnit manual at:** http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers.

Comment: did you mean that i should set data into the "data/xyz.yml" file ?

Comment: You would need to add the @dataProvider annotation to the docblock comment for the test function. You can find more information on this page: http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/02/01/phpunit-and-magento-yes-you-can.html under the heading 'Data Providers'. There's also some information in the PHPUnit manual at: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers.

Comment: i have one more trouble in MTAF custom test-case - "i have my custom module and i have add one tab in the admin panel in my module, then the problem is i'm getting the URL for my module is without /admin and in browser.yml i have given admin URL with /admin...so how to deal with it !!! can you please help for it.

Comment: when I'm trying to add "asserprecondition()" function for my own module names "mtaf" and when trying to run i'm getting the error "Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Could not find class "" in "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php".' in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\PEAR\PHPUnit\Util\Skeleton\Test.php:123
Stack trace:" can any one help for the same. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.